# Save dynamically generated textfield from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a table which is being dynamically generated based on the user input, in some cases rows have a textfield and i want to save the values updated by the user in the textfield by in the MySql database. e.g:

Actual Code:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$sql3[0]."</td><td>".$row1[2]."</td>
      <td><input type='text' class='span1' value='".$recieved."'/>
      </td><td>".$status."</td></tr>";
```

Simplified example:

```
//some user input e.g Microsoft

Table: 
item             quantity      received
Windows 7          1000       'textfield'
Office 2007         200        nothing required
Windows 8          20000      'textfield'
```

Now i want to save the values entered in the textfield and update them in the database. The problem is i am not sure how to define an `id` (id of the textfield) which can be read using a javascript so that i know which textfield i am currently talking about.

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: @Stewie - Please check the updated question, maybe that helps!

Comment: why not use a simple ajax submit? easy, allow you to use PHP, let user on the same page.

Comment: @CharlesForest - That is what i want to do, but for that i need to get the values from the textfields, but the textfields are being dynamically generated so i don't know how to get those values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output should look like (*linebreaks for reading **only** -- not for use in actual code*)

```
var .= '<tr class="someClass">';
var .=   '<td>'.$row["item"].'</td>';
var .=   '<td>'.$row["quantity"].'</td>';
var .=   '<td>';if(!empty($row["received"])){ var .= '<input type="text" value="'.$row["received"].'" id="'.$row['id'].'" />'; }else{ var.= '<input type="text" value="default_value" id="'.$row['id'].'"/>'; } 
var .=   '</td>';
var .= '</tr>';

return var;
```

Now you use jQuery's AJAX function to pass over the value ID of the 'row'.

```
$(".someClass input").live('keypress', function(e){
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if(code == 13){ // if we pressed enter
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the default submission behavior
    var ourId = this.id;
    var updatedText = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'path/to/my/update/file.php',
      data: 'id='+ourId+'text='+updatedText,
      success: function(data){
        //our post to the file was successful. 
        //The file returns data and that data is available as an object.
        //We declare it as 'data' in the success: function(data) string.
       $("#someContainer").append(data); //append our data returned to #someContainer

      }
    });
  }
});
```

Now that we've passed the ID of the input field (which is also associated directly to the row we want to update) to our PHP file, we can parse the data we need and use it to update the database accordingly.

```
<?php
  //include our sql.connect file

  $ourId = $_POST['id'];
  $updatedText = $_POST['text'];

  $q = mysql_query("UPDATE 'our_table' SET received='".$updatedText."' WHERE id = ".$ourId);
?>
```

I hope this is what you want.

**EDIT 1** -- *per user request*

```
var .= '<td>'; //open the data cell    
//the below line checks to see if the row 'received' is **NOT** a empty database result
if(!empty($row["received"])){
  //our row is not empty, change the value of the input field to our $row['received'] value
  var .= '<input type="text" value="'.$row["received"].'" id="'.$row['id'].'" />'; 
}else{ 
  //our row was empty, or our row returned null. either way, we use "default_value" as our value, which will literally print as a textbox with the words default_value in it.
  var.= '<input type="text" value="default_value" id="'.$row['id'].'"/>'; 
} 
var . = '</td>'; //close the data cell
```

**EDIT 2**

Changed  to reflect a unique class generated only by the rows in our PHP file. Also changed the keypress function's selector to reflect only inputs *within* our uniquely generated rows.

Comment: This is exactly what i want, also just to clarify your code works when the return key is pressed on the textfield right? Also could you please elaborate on this line:
`'<td>';if(!empty($row["received"])){ var .= '<input type="text" value="'.$row["received"].'" id="'.$row['id'].'" />'; }else{ var.= '<input type="text" value="default_value" id="'.$row['id'].'"/>'; }`

Comment: Also the `('input')` tag is working on other textfields which aren't dynamically created.

Comment: Yes. when the return key is pressed the data will be sent to the php file. e.preventDefault(); stops the form submission and the natural 'refresh' of the page, so we can avoid that behavior. Also, you can change var .= '<tr>'; to var .='<tr class="someClass">'; then you can change $('input') to $('.someClass input'); so you only target inputs within the row that has a class of .someClass.

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML add the name:

```
<input type='text' class='span1' name="received[]" value='".$recieved."'/>
```

in PHP:

```
$received = $_REQUEST['received']
print_r($received);
```

and you will know what to do.

Alternatively, you can do `received[$id]` where `$id` is the primary identifier of the row.

Comment: Is it possible that i can get the value of `received[some_textfield]` in javascript so that i can use ajax and save the data. I need to get the ID and the entered value in javascript

Comment: well, there are multiple ways to do it in JS, but using the array method won't work then, you'll have to do it by id or if you are using jquery, you can do the traversal

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
item_id     mediumint(8)
```

or even `int`

That will be long enough but you also need usr_id or dunno if you have that already in mind that would be enough.