# Getting value of dynamically generated textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that has been generated dynamically using PHP. The table has a few textfields which are being used to update the database based on the row. This question can be referred at: [Complete question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726265/save-dynamically-generated-textfield-from-php), based on one for the answer i am using javascript which gets the textfield value when enter is pressed. The javascript being used is:

```
$("#details input").live('keypress', function (e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (code == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ourId = $(this).id;
        var updatedText = $(this).val;

        alert(updatedText);
    }
});
```

However for some reason `$(this)` isn't returning the expected result.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `not returning expected result`? Is the `alert` printing wrong values?

Comment: Sorry about that, i am unable to get the id of the textfield, the value using `val()` now works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing concepts there. `$(this).id --> this.id OR $(this).attr('id')` and `$(this).val --> $(this).val()`. Instead of `live()` which is deprecated, use `on()` for delegation.

```
$("#details").on('keypress', 'input', function(){
    // Bla
});
```

Comment: I was using on before, but it did not work as the fields were being dynamically generated, hence i had to use `live()`

Comment: You need to use the event delegation form of `on()` like I posted. You can read about it at the JQ API

Comment: Read the docs, it should work. You have to make sure that the container it's not dynamically generated or else attach it to the closes static element.

Answer (score 4):

`val` is a method and not property so it be should used like a function.

Change `$(this).val` to `$(this).val()`

And to get the id of the input element just use `this.id`. `id` is a property of the dom elemdnt.